# How to get RAM usage details of an iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ram, iphone-security

Is there any way to get available RAM details of an iPhone from settings or using any cheat code; without using any 3rd part application.

I am NOT asking for any code to get available RAM details. I am asking for something native provided by Apple where I can get the usage details of my iphone. Like someplace in device settings.

AGAIN, Please read my question properly. I said, I am not looking for any Objective-C/Swift Code to get available memory. I know how to do that. I am looking for something in device settings where I can see how much RAM I have in my device and how much left, just like device memory.

Comment: Hey Phillip, did you see my question properly? I know the code that how to get available memory. Please read my question before making any decision. I asked for something in the device settings.

Comment: Someone may have marked it as a duplicate, but I didn't.  I marked it to be closed because, as far as I can tell, it's not about programming.  (And your update to the question just confirmed that!)